# How to use "after which" in a sentence?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, relative-clauses, pied-piping

Do

> They visited Brighton, after which they went to Northern Ireland

and

> They visited Brighton, which they went to Northern Ireland after

have the same meaning?

And does it mean, *visiting Brighton, they went to Northern Ireland?*

Comment: It oughtn't be a preposition that you finish your sentence on.  Or with.

Comment: The first sentence is more correct than the second one.  It means that they first visited Brighton.  After they visited Brighton, they visited Northern Ireland

Comment: @VictorBazarov Considering that your sentences end with prepositions, I'm not sure whether you were joking.  Even if you were though, for those that might follow such advice, the "rule" that says it's grammatically incorrect to end a sentence with a preposition (stranded preposition) is actually a [myth](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/11/grammar-myths-prepositions).

Comment: It's OK with some and especially so if it's a prepositional verb.  The "myth" is not debunked in that article.  It's restated and claimed as such, and a humorous illustration given, no more.  Depends on whether you subscribe to "descriptive grammar" or "prescriptive".  It's not completely inconceivable that "after which" could be split similarly to what the OP has in the second example, but it just **doesn't sound at all understandable**.

Comment: @VictorBazarov Oh, I agree that the second example is not correct.  It's just that it is incorrect for other reasons than the dubious stranded preposition rule.

Comment: @VictorBazarov You're promoting a Zombie Rule.  Please don't!  All clued-in prescriptive grammarians since Fowler have agreed that prepositions can end sentences.  Fowler himself called it a superstition: "It was once a cherished superstition that prepositions must be kept true to their name and placed before the word they govern in spite of the incurable English instinct for putting them late, [ . . . ]"  And that was back in 1926! For more discussion, please see *Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of English Usage*, starting on page 763.

Comment: I'll leap to @VictorBazarov's defence, and say that to me he was clearly joking.

Answer (score 2):

The second sentence:

**They visited Brighton, which they went to Northern Ireland after**

makes no sense to me. I would expect:

**They visited Brighton and went to Northern Ireland *afterwards*.**

To *go to* a place means to visit a place. You can substitute **go to** for the verb **visit**.

> Did you visit Northern Ireland?
>
> Did you go to Northern Ireland?
>
> They visited Northern Ireland, which they went to, after seeing
>   Brighton.
>
> They went to Northern Ireland, which they visited after seeing Brighton.
>
> They went to Brighton, after which they visited Northern Ireland.
>
> They went to Brighton and went on to Northern Ireland after(wards). <sup>without the relative "which"</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Normally, a "preposition relative pronoun" (eg *after which*, *to whom*, *by what*) can be broken up and the preposition moved to the end of the clause, eg

> This is the entry after which it came/which it came after
>
> That is the person to whom I spoke/who I spoke to

and the latter form is much more common in speech than the former.

But in your example, this doesn't work, and I'm not entirely sure why.

*After which* can quite happily refer to the whole of the (action of the) preceding clause or sentence. But if you split them, as in your second example, *which* cannot easily refer to the whole predicate, but looks for a noun phrase (and here finds only "Brighton").

So your second sentence is not natural. But I cannot fully account for why not.